# SQL / Doctrine : Is it possible to get this result using group by?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, group-by, doctrine

I'm honestly not that good with group by in SQL.
I have two entities 1) Blocks 2) Sets.

Each blocks contains many sets.
In my table, this is mapped by a ManyToOne in Sets.
Each sets has a column named "block" which refers to blocks id. Simple.

However, when i'm trying to get all the blocks or all the sets, I get, of course an array like this :
(I made the arrays shorters on purpose for readability)

**for Sets :**

```
array:34 [▼
  0 => Sets {#833 ▼
    -id: 1
    -name: "Alpha"
    -year: "1993-08"
    -icon: "000"
    -block: Blocks {#836 ▶}
  }
  1 => Sets {#838 ▼
    -id: 2
    -name: "Arabian Nights"
    -year: "1993-12"
    -icon: "003"
    -block: Blocks {#836 ▶}
  }
  2 => Sets {#839 ▶}
  3 => Sets {#841 ▶}
  4 => Sets {#842 ▶}
  5 => Sets {#844 ▶}
]
```

**And for Blocks :**

```
array:27 [▼
  0 => Blocks {#836 ▶}
  1 => Blocks {#840 ▼
    -id: 2
    -name: "Ice Age"
    -year: "1995"
    -description: "The Ice Age block is the first block of sets, consisting of the large expansion Ice Age in June 1995 and two small expansions, Alliances in June 1996 and Coldsn ▶"
  }
  2 => Blocks {#843 ▼
    -id: 3
    -name: "Mirage"
    -year: "1996"
    -description: "The Mirage block is the second block of sets, consisting of the large expansion Mirage followed by two small expansions, Visions and Weatherlight. The block cam ▶"
  }
  3 => Blocks {#846 ▼
    -id: 4
    -name: "Tempest"
    -year: "1997"
    -description: """
      Tempest block, officially called the Rath Cycle, is the third Magic block, spanning 1997–1998. It encompasses three sets: the large expansion Tempest and the tw ▶



      The keywords introduced in this block were buyback and shadow. Three creature types (Licids, Slivers, and Spikes) also debuted here. 
      """
  }
  4 => Blocks {#849 ▶}
  5 => Blocks {#852 ▶}
  6 => Blocks {#855 ▶}
  7 => Blocks {#858 ▶}
]
```

**But, the array I want to get, is this :**

**An array of every blocks, and their respectives sets inside.**

```
array:16 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => "Outside Block"
    "year" => "199X"
    "content" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        "name" => "Alpha"
        "icon" => "000"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        "name" => "Arabian Nights"
        "icon" => "003"
      ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▶]
  2 => array:3 [▶]
  3 => array:3 [▶]
]
```

As you can see, I managed to do it using loops inside my PHP code.
But I wonder, is this impossible to do using SQL ?
Is it possible to create an array using group by to get all the blocks, in differents column, and their containing sets in every row ?

Comment: Does that mean you are already using SQL? Where do you store your data? How do you generate the arrays?

Comment: I got the first and second array using findby of Doctrine ORM all it does is a simple select with a leftjoin of the blocks.

I got the third array after a foreach and a sort of the first array, but I wonder if it is actually possible to get it using basic SQL or if it is impossible.